# JQGrid with Bootstrap Multiselect and Custom Save

Tags: jqgrid

I have 2 requirements I need to solve for.  I'm using a JQGrid on an aspx page with other form controls.  Saving the main form generates a database id that is populated in a hidden field.  If the hidden field is empty, I don't want to save the grid record because I need the db id first.  If the hidden field has a value, I want to save the row with a editurl.

The second part is related to a Bootstrap multiselect in one of the grid columns (I need the filtering capability).  When a user selects a value from the multiselect I'd like to populate the PERNR column with the value selected.  I can't use the onchange event for the multiselect since if the user doesn't change from the first option obviously it won't trigger the event.

How can I solve these 2 issues?

```
var roleDdlItems = $.parseJSON($("input[id$='hdfRoleDdlItems']").val());
$("#grdParticipants").jqGrid({
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: 'Table',
        page: function (obj) { return 1; },
        total: function (obj) { return 2; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.ItemCount; },
        id: "0"
    },
    caption: getParticipantCaption(),//"Participants",
    pgbuttons: false,
    recordtext: "Total: {2}",
    emptyrecords: "",
    loadtext: "Loading...",
    pgtext: "",
    datatype: function () {
        UpdateParticipant("getParticipants");
    },
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    //        serializeGridData: function (postData) { return JSON.stringify(postData); },
    colNames: ['Id', 'PERNR', 'Name', 'Email', 'RoleId', 'Role', 'Active', 'Updated'],
    colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', hidden: true, editable: true, hidedlg: true },
                { name: 'PERNR', index: 'PERNR', hidden: true, editable: true, hidedlg: true },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 200, align: "center", editable: true, edittype: "select", 
                    editoptions: { value: function () {
                        var ITDdlItems = $.parseJSON($("input[id$='hdfITEmployeesDdlItems']").val());
                        var s = "";
                        if (ITDdlItems.Table4 && ITDdlItems.Table4.length) {
                            for (var i = 0, l = ITDdlItems.Table4.length; i < l; i++) {
                                var item = ITDdlItems.Table4[i];
                                s += item.PERNR + ":" + item.Name + ";";
                            }
                        }
                        s = s.substring(0, s.length - 1);
                        return s;
                    },
                        dataInit: function (e) {
                            $(e).multiselect({
                                maxHeight: 200,
                                enableFiltering: true,
                                filterPlaceholder: "Search Employees",
                                enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
                                templates: {
                                    filter: '<li class="multiselect-item filter"><div class="input-group"><input class="form-control input-sm multiselect-search" id="txtITEmployeeFilter" type="text"></div></li>',
                                    filterClearBtn: "<span class='input-group-btn'><button class='btn btn-default input-sm multiselect-clear-filter' type='button'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i></button><button class='btn btn-primary input-sm multiselect-clear-filter' type='button' onclick='javascript:searchEmployees(&quot;#" + e.id + "&quot;);'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i></button></span>"
                                },
                                onDropdownHide: function (event) {
                                    $(e).multiselect("updateButtonText");
                                    $(e).multiselect("updateSelectAll");
                                }
//                                    onChange: function(option, checked) {
//                                        var selectedOption = $("#" + e.id + " option:selected").val();
//                                        alert(selectedOption);
//                                    }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                },
                { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 250, align: "center", editable: false },
                { name: 'RoleId', index: 'RoleId', hidden: true, editable: true, hidedlg: true },
                { name: 'Role', index: 'Role', width: 175, align: "center", editable: true, edittype: "select",
                    editoptions: { value: function () {
                        var roleDdlItems = $.parseJSON($("input[id$='hdfRoleDdlItems']").val());
                        var s = "";
                        if (roleDdlItems.Table3 && roleDdlItems.Table3.length) {
                            for (var i = 0, l = roleDdlItems.Table3.length; i < l; i++) {
                                var item = roleDdlItems.Table3[i];
                                s += item.Id + ":" + item.Role + ";";
                            }
                        }
                        s = s.substring(0, s.length - 1);
                        return s;
                    },
                        dataInit: function (e) {
                            $(e).multiselect({
                                maxHeight: 200,
                                onDropdownHide: function (event) {
                                    $(e).multiselect("updateButtonText");
                                    $(e).multiselect("updateSelectAll");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }

                },
                {
                    name: 'Active', index: 'Active', hidden: false, width: 75, align: "center", editable: true, hidedlg: true,
                    edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "true:false", defaultValue: "Active" },
                    formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: true }
                },
                { name: 'Updated', index: 'Updated', width: 100, align: "center", editable: false, sorttype: "date",
                    formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'n/j/y g:i A' }
                }
    ],
    rowNum: 5000,
    autoWidth: true,
    rowList: [],
    pager: '#pgrParticipants',
    toppager: true,
    sortname: 'Name',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'asc'
});

$('#grdParticipants').navGrid("#pgrParticipants", {edit: false, add: false, del: true, refresh: false, search: false, view: false});

$('#grdParticipants').inlineNav('#pgrParticipants',
// the buttons to appear on the toolbar of the grid
            {
            edit: true,
            add: true,
            del: true,
            cancel: true,
            editParams: {
                keys: true
            },
            addParams: {
                addRowParams: {
                    keys: true
                }
            }
        });
            $('#grdParticipants').navSeparatorAdd('#pgrParticipants', {
        sepclass: 'ui-separator',
        sepcontent: '',
        position: 'last'
    });

    $('#grdParticipants').navButtonAdd('#pgrParticipants',
    {
        buttonicon: "ui-icon-help",
        title: "Roles & Responsibilities Matrix",
        caption: "Roles & Responsibilities Matrix",
        position: "last",
        onClickButton: showRoleMatrix
    });
```

*** EDIT  ***

The datatype function contains an ajax call that populates the grid.  I’m using this based on an example someone else in my company provided.  I’ll look around today for a better method, as it sounds this isn’t the best way.  Maybe using url, which I stumbled across today.

This is a tab interface to track outages that will ultimately have a total of 5 separate JQGrids.  When the page initially loads for a new outage this grid is on the first tab and is empty.  It would only contain records if they’re editing an existing outage.  In that instance, I would populate values in the main outage form controls and load data in the grid.   The UpdateParticipant function seemed work well for this as it allows me to check for that hidden field before deciding whether a db call is even needed.

The PERNR is an employee id that the user doesn’t need to know, hence hidden.  It’s not strictly confidential info, but we don’t advertise it either.  They only need to see Name and Email (maybe) based on the value selected from the Name multiselect.  Id will be a Participant Id generated by the database after the grid data is saved.  Which can’t happen until the main outage form above is saved because I need that unique Outage Id as a foreign key for the participants.  This attaches a participant to an outage and becomes the unique Id for the grid rows.

The `selectedOption = $("#" + e.id + " option:selected").val()` is commented out, but was only  to trigger onchange for that specific Bootstrap Multiselect.  The Role multiselect didn’t have an onchange function registered in code.  So yes, it was for one element only.  As mentioned previously, I was trying to use this to populate PERNR on a Name select.  I need PERNR not Name to save to the db later.  To solve for this I’m using the custom formatter on that column so I’ve since removed that onchange function for the Name multiselect.  The `ITDdlItems = $.parseJSON($("input[id$='hdfITEmployeesDdlItems']").val())` contains a json list of employee names and PERNRs to populate the Name multiselect.  That works fine so this isn’t code relevant.

The only thing I need to figure out is how to perform a check for OutageId in the hidden field before the grid data is posted to the server.  Thinking about it last night, if all else fails, I’ll let it post to the server and check there for the OutageId.  I just don’t like posting if it isn’t going to make a db call. I’d share a demo somewhere if I knew how.  This is an internal application so my options are limited.

Comment: Could you provide a demo which demonstrates the usage of Bootstrap Multiselect and "Custom Save". The demo should use non-minimized code of jqGrid. One can debug you demo and then find the solution of your problem.

Comment: Honestly, I've never gotten so stuck trying to figure anything out that I've had to create a demo and I have no idea how to do it.  Guess I was hoping to at least find out if I can even use editurl when I'm only triggering it conditionally.  Maybe use the editurl, but only save to the db on the server if the hidden field has a value.  Or if I have to use clientarray.  Or what grid function I can hook into for grab the selected value of the Bootstrap Multiselect. I tried editParams with the oneditfunc but couldn't access the Multiselect so I'm thinking this event triggers after it's saved

Comment: Success on the 2nd requirement!  Ran across custom formatters.  Added a custom formatter function to the column with the Multiselect.  Not sure if this is the ideal solution, but it works.  Now I just have to figure out how to suppress save until that hidden field is populated.

function getPERNR(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var pernr = $("#" + options.rowId + " option:selected").val();
    $('#grdParticipants').jqGrid('setCell', options.rowId, "PERNR", pernr);
    return cellvalue;
}

Comment: Many problems could exist just if you use jqGrid in the wrong way. For example you use `datatype` as function. Why? In 99% cases which I seen it was the wrong way. How you fill the data of the grid? Do you make some Ajax request to the server inside of `UpdateParticipant`? What values have the data which you use to fill the grid? Two rows of data would be enough. Which rowid you use? Why you need two hidden columns `Id` and `PERNR`? What is native id of the data (rowid)?

Comment: You use **two** `multiselect` controls for editing of one row but you use `selectedOption = $("#" + e.id + " option:selected").val()`. Do you have really **one** element in `$("#" + e.id + " option:selected")`? You use `ITDdlItems = $.parseJSON($("input[id$='hdfITEmployeesDdlItems']").val())` with unclear contain. It's difficult to understand what you do without to know the meaning of the input and the value.

Comment: I edited my original post with additional info and responses to your questions.

Comment: I give up.  Tried extending the grid (ajaxRowOptions >> beforeSend) with limited success.  I was able to prevent calling the web service if the Outage Id was blank, but the row got stuck in edit mode.  Attempted to use saveRow with clientArray to  just save locally and get it out of edit to no avail.  Maybe it's not possible from this function.  Decided to just let the grid call the web service and will deal with no Outage Id on the server.  Not ideal, but it should work.  I'll still have to save the whole grid when the main form is initially saved.  Sigh.

Comment: Sorry, but all what you posted contains a lot of unneeded details, but no clear code which can be used to create the demo. If you want to solve the problem you should just create simple JSFiddle code with grid willing with local data and which use Bootstrap multiselect in a simple way. If the code will do not exactly what you need then me or other could help you.

Comment: Well, you asked a bunch of question so I answered them.   If you can only help if I post a demo, state that instead of asking a list of questions.  If I get bored I'll try to figure out how to create a demo.  Triggering a function before callback shouldn't be this complicated though.  There are multiple ways to do it on every other control I've worked with over the past 15+ years.  And I don't need someone's code to at least give some guidance on how to accomplish it.

Comment: I didn't hear about Bootstrap multiselect at all before reading of your question. I could try to help you, but I need **to debug** the code which uses Bootstrap multiselect to see what it do and which problems could exist during integration. Please don't copy your existing code and define all values directly as `var`. You can use http://jsfiddle.net/, http://codepen.io/ or any other. If you really need Ajax requests then you can use echo service of jsfiddle for example. See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/6/ as an example.